# Segal's axioms for CFT

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

In Segal's papers about Conformal Field theory, [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~blockj/scfts/segal.pdf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eblockj/scfts/segal.pdf), in section $1$, he describes the evolution of a system (a string moving about in a manifold $M$) by a one parameter group $(e^{iHt})$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. If $t>0$, the contraction operator $e^{-Ht}$ is integral, i.e, $$(e^{-Ht}\psi)(\omega)=\int_{LM}K_t(\omega,\omega')\psi(\omega')D\omega',$$ where the kernel $K_t$ is of the form $$K_t(\omega,\omega')=\int e^{-S(\sigma)}D\sigma,$$ where the integral is taken over all the paths $\sigma:[0,t]\to LM$ from $\omega$ to $\omega'$. The point of that, which is the crucial property and why it's a conformal theory, is that the functional $S$ only depends on the conformal structure of the cylinder $\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,t]$.\
But why? Segal just point that and does not give any proof or hint. I couldn't find anything about this online. Maybe it's too obvius but i can't figure it by myself. Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: It's a definition: if S doesn't have that then it's not a *string theory* string

Comment: So why it's not every field theory conformal?

Comment: most field theories depend on *distances*. conformal ones do not (because dilatations rescale distances). hopefully this is at least intuitively clear